# Converting line breaks in MySQL database for CURL connection

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I am storing a block of text as `VARCHAR(300)` in a MySQL database. The user posts this text via a textarea and it is escaped with `mysql_real_escape_string` before insertion.

I am then pulling this text and posting it via CURL with this PHP code:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handlers[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("Text" => $text));
```

The only issue is, the receiving URL expects linebreaks to be encoded as `%0a`. I assume that linebreaks are stored as `\r\n` in MySQL.

How do I reliably convert the line breaks stored in MySQL to `%0a` before posting the text via CURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to [`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your variable.

```
$urlencoded_text = urlencode( $text );
curl_setopt($curl_handlers[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("Text" => $urlencoded_text ));
```

However `\r\n` will be converted to `%0D%0A` (`\r` => `%0D`, `\n` => `%0A`) so you may need to clean it up if you really want to send only `%0A` for line breaks.

**Update:**

To tranform `\r\n` into `\n` simply use PHP's [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function:

```
$text = str_replace( "\r\n", "\n", $text );
```

Note that double quotes are required to interpret `\r\n`.

Then:

```
$urlencoded_text = urlencode( $text );
```

`$urlencoded_text` now contains only `%0A` in place of `\r\n`.

Comment: The issue, as it turns out, is that the `\r\n` is counted as two characters, instead of just a single line break, so `urlencode` would actually not help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the line breaks were indeed stored as `\r\n` in MySQL, so I needed to replace this with just `\n` (which is correctly accepted as `%0A` on the receiving end).

```
$text = str_replace("\r\n","\n",$text);
```